# deletion of objects in bucket using object tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, boto3, delete-file

I have to basically upload some objects in s3 bucket. Once done I had to do their object tagging which I did using put_object_tagging (). Now I am trying to filter the objects based on these tags so that I can delete the objects based on tags. I am completely struck.

```
while j!=10:
  if j%2==0:
  response1 = client.put_object_tagging(
      Bucket='shivam1052061',
      Key='%d.txt' % (j),
      Tagging={
          'TagSet': [
              {
                  'Key': 'notdivby2',
                  'Value': '2no'
              },
          ]
       }
    )
 j=j+1
```

i wrote some logic for the above problem and it is listed below.But I dont think it is the optimised version of the code. If anyone knows how to optimise this , please tell.

```
    for key in bucket.objects.all():
var=key.key
response = client.get_object_tagging(
    Bucket='shivam1052061',
    Key=var,
)
tagK = response['TagSet'][0]['Key']
tagV = response['TagSet'][0]['Value']
print(tagK + " ")
print(tagV + " ")
if tagK == deltagK and tagV == deltagV:
  #  print("4-done" + " ")
    response3 = client.delete_object(
        Bucket='shivam1052061',
        Key=var
    )
```

Comment: So, what is the problem with your code?

Comment: I am unable to filter or search objects based on the tags i have set. Shouldn't there be some pre defined function using which i should be able to access tags of objects and manipulate with it and as i am not able to find anything I have not written the code about the same till now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work,

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

contents = s3.list_objects(Bucket='shivam1052061').get('Contents')
delkeys = []

for content in contents:
    try:
        response = s3.get_object_tagging(
            Bucket='shivam1052061',
            Key=content.get('Key')
        )
        for tag in response.get('TagSet'):
            if tag.get('Key') == 'notdivby2' and tag.get('Value') == '2no':
            delkeys.append(key)
    except:
        pass

print(delkeys)
```

but it will take so many times. There is no way to naturally filter the object with tags, so you can call the list of objects and call again each tags for the object, check the tag what you want or not and get the `delkeys` to delete.

Comment: Thanks ! I think this might also work. I wrote something similar to this only i guess . Can you please tell me which one is the more optimised one and why! I have edited it above . thanks in advance

Comment: I do some modification. if the object didn't have any tag then it will occur the error so I use try and catch. Also there can be several tag keys, so I added a for loop.